# Read Javascript Script to Figure Out Which Radio Button to Press

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This program is supposed to find a specific script element, and by using that element figure out which  radio button to press.

I have used this line to find the correct script element. I've tested this and it seems to work.

```
scriptElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[contains(.,'Press')]")
```

The html looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    question = {"Choices":[{"DisplayContent":"Option 1","Press":false},{"DisplayContent":"Option 2","Press":false},{"DisplayContent":"Option 3","Press":true},{"DisplayContent":"Option 4","Press":false};
</script>
```

As you can see I'm trying to figure out which option has Press:true, and then have selenium select that one.

Comment: you can execute your own script using selenium and have it return this array... I think it would be as simple as "return question"... though it seems like this stuff would be in the markup as well.  Post the resulting form.

Comment: @pcalkins I added ".get_attribute("innerHTML")" to the end of "scriptElm". Now I have all the text in a str and just need to try to get the program to decipher it.

Comment: don't know python, but maybe take a look here:  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp